# Type TTextKey cannot be used to index type TOption

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can not understand why ts complains about `return option[optionTextKey]` with this message:

```
Type TTextKey cannot be used to index type TOption
```

Code:

```js
type Props<
    TTextKey,
    TOption extends (TTextKey extends string ? { [key in TTextKey]: string; } : string),
> = (
    {
        optionTextKey: TTextKey;
        options: TOption[];
    }
    |
    {
        options: string[];
        optionTextKey?: never;
    }
) & {
    name: string;
    placeholder: string;
};

function LinkDropdown<
    TTextKey,
    TOption extends (TTextKey extends string ? { [key in TTextKey]: string; } : string),
>({
    options,
    optionTextKey,
    name,
    placeholder,
}: Props<TTextKey, TOption>): ReactElement
   // some code

    const getOptionText = (option: TOption, optionTextKey: TTextKey) => {
        if ('string' === typeof option) return option;
        // ts complains here
        return option[optionTextKey];
    };

   // some code
}
```

This message is gone if I make `TOption` this way:

```js
TOption extends TTextKey extends { [key in TTextKey]: string; }
```

**upd**

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the specific question, here?  Is it "why is there an error" or "how should I write this instead"?  They are related but different questions with related but different answers.  There's an error because TS can't do control flow analysis with generics and especially not with generic *conditional types* as in your example.  (more)

Comment: (continued) You expect checking `typeof option === "string"` to narrow `TOption` (and possibly even `TTextKey`) but it has no such effect. The canonical open issue in GitHub asking for better support for this is [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please [edit] to explicitly ask a well-defined question that this doesn't fully address.

Comment: "Why is there this an error? and how I can fix it? is it possible withiout any and type casting?" is... three questions.  Could you pick one to be primary?

Comment: "how can i fix it" - or I need to point it out in post?

Comment: I don't know @jcalz if you saw my message above so I mention you here, thanks!

Comment: I saw it but I don't currently have an answer yet. Yes, though, you should [edit] the post to ask a single well-defined question.

Comment: If you want to be able to narrow by checking `typeof option === "string"` then `option` must be of a union type and not of a generic type. If I make the appropriate change it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdJQkW). This might not be the "best" way to fix it, e.g., it's not clear to me why you don't constrain `K` to `string` anyway, but that seems to be out of scope here. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an official answer; if not, what am I continuing to miss?

Comment: You can write an official answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript cannot currently use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (e.g., an `if`/`else` check) to narrow or re-[constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) type parameters.  In

```
const getOptionText = (option: O, optionTextKey: K) => {
  if ('string' === typeof option) return option;      
  return option[optionTextKey];
};
```

you apparently expect checking whether `option` is a `string` to have some effect on the type parameter `O`, which should then presumably also have an effect on the type parameter `K`.  But TypeScript doesn't work this way. Checking `option` only affects the type of `option`, not `O`.  Indeed you cannot assume that `O` is a subtype of `string`, because it might be *wider*.  For example, it could be that `option` is `string`, but `O` is actually the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | {a: string}`.  Currently there's nothing good TypeScript can do to `O` for such checks, so it does nothing.  And then you get errors when `O` and `K` are still unaffected in the line `option[optionTextKey]`.

There are a number of open requests in GitHub trying to get some better support.  Probably the most relevant one for your question is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), which is specifically about generic [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and since your `O` is constrained to a conditional type that depends on the generic `K`, this missing feature is at least related.  But even if this were implemented it might not solve the issue you're having.  For now, at least, if you want to use control flow analysis to work, you will have to switch away from generics and towards unions.

---

So, one way to make your code compile is to replace the generic `O` with a relevant concrete union type:

```
const getOptionText = (
  option: string | { [P in K & string]: string },
  optionTextKey: K & string
) => {
  if ('string' === typeof option) return option;
  return option[optionTextKey];
};
```

Now since `option` is of the union type `string | { ⋯ }`, a check of `typeof option` can narrow `option` to either side of the union.  If it's the `string` side, then `return option` is a `string`. If it's the object side, then `option` can be indexed with `optionTextKey`.  Note that I had to make the type of `optionTextKey` the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `K & string` to allow it to be used as a key type, since your `K` is not already constrained as such.  It's quite possible that there are a lot of changes one could make to improve the code example here, but I consider this out of scope for the question as asked.  The change I've shown here is the minimal one I can think of which works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIAUBOB7SBnAPMWsDSAabWAeVmgA9RoA7AEzVgApczKb7Y1REBLagc1gB+WAG9YAbXiw+eALoAuTtz78A3LAC+sJV14CAlIQB8sALxMioojlSgeyagBUKoXNHBLcam7DsPqNCViCTkfHG0AHzFff0cXSndwISVqaAA3aERwnD9Ie0cg5X1+UJzNA1gAMhjc2GoAQwBbaF0VARycSAAbBoBjaAALZG7aLLaS8p9gADMAV2o+guoSXn4AGT4AawARFEhaZAB3aiwcAiJSV3YGZlYqOgY9VWExSS2PGRXcRWLVDW0E1URmAxkY1ls+QCaEIkOWCTcHlh9Wa0GRPX6QxGY0QhE0SiQqEwBBIxgMSga1HAtVgAHpaZxkC1YH1kGMQDhWYFQLB+NBQMQofFXOYmHFqMF8Hl4a4kl5KmZTBDcjwZkwAOTPATq8xmCwQGDINXiyqIflzRArcWdOkM0AMVlNDF8BiDLLQXxm0AWq1C6gScUIpJhIiaaY4emM5ms9maECzBZLAKwTbUXb7Q4nM54ZFXNiPJgsa4FrWCETiKRfeRAjpaHR-QwmcFEcUwlt+oNIoiNFro3oDYajLJ4gn7YlS4hkilUmmRtBMuAxj1ELlcXn8wUyyiixixP01wTRCvSWQsGql36lrTIuEBTuePDVBv8IgKpW+VUa0s6vX6qDQI1pQCU1zUtIDHBtL0fXA-1A1lDwQwiaZNCAA)